# Displaying Json array returnd from http get

Tags: json, angular, http, ngfor

I want to display content from the firebase I get the data from HTTP get request and I want to display it using ngFor

here is how i get the data

```
///a service
 getMessages(){
    return this.http.get('https://bigproject-dd88e.firebaseio.com/data.json')
    .map((response:Response)=>{
const data: Message[]=response.json();
return data;
    }

    ).catch(
      (error:Response)=>{

        return Observable.throw('something went wrong');
      }

    );
  }
```

and here is my component

```
export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit {
  Message=[];
  constructor(private global:GlobalService) {

   }
  ngOnInit() {

    this.GenaerateMessages();
  }
  GenaerateMessages(){
    this.global.getMessages().subscribe(
      Message=>this.Message=Message
    );
  }

}
```

and here is my HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of Message | keyvalue">

     <p>{{item.value|json}}</p>
</div>
```

I get this on the screen

[ { "email": "loay-gohan@hotmail.com", "message": "loayy", "name": "loay", "phone": "123123123" } ]

[ { "email": "example@example", "message": "hi", "name": "..", "phone": "123123" } ]

how can I reach the inside fields name, message, phone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like each`item.value` contains one array with one object. If this is a case you can reach it like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of Message | keyvalue">
  <div>EMAIL: {{ item.value[0].email }}</div>
  <div>MESSAGE: {{ item.value[0].message }}</div>
  <div>NAME: {{ item.value[0].name }}</div>
  <div>PHONE: {{ item.value[0].phone }}</div>

  <pre>{{ item.value | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

If `item.value` array has more than one object you might want to loop it wit additional inner `ngFor`
You do not use `value.key`. Don't you need it?